# Android: Fragments in Support Libraries work but Regular libraries do not

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have the following code...

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
...
public class LevelSelectorFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  ...
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);
    this.mAdapter = new LevelFragmentPagerAdapter(this);
  }
  private static class LevelFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public LevelFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity a) {
        super(a.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Level1Fragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }

  }
}
```

This works fine but when I change form FragmentActivity to Activity and change the imports as follows...

import org.gleason.superhockey.fragment.Level1Fragment;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class LevelSelectorFragmentActivity extends Activity {

private static final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 2;
private LevelFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);
    this.mAdapter = new LevelFragmentPagerAdapter(this);
}

private static class LevelFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public LevelFragmentPagerAdapter(Activity a) {
        super(a.getFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Level1Fragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }

}

}
```

I get the following ClassNotFound...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.gleason.superhockey.LevelSelectorFragmentActivity$LevelFragmentPagerAdapter

For an example I am using [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/supportv13/app/FragmentPagerSupport.java)

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that your library .jar is in the wrong directory or is added twice to the project. Make sure your support library .jar is in /libs folder. Then check Build Path and remove the support library from it (if it's there). Clean project.

Comment: I am using eclipse so it is managing my classpath. Now I do have both support jars in my classpath but I can't see where that would make the difference. Notice the CNFE is for the inner-class NOT A SUPPORT CLASS.

Comment: I don't mean classpath but Build Path. In other words: your libs should not be available in the projects Referenced Libraries. But you're right - I was always writing bout the support lib instead of some other external lib.

Comment: Yeah I still don't think this is the issue since it is an internal class but I could be wrong. I just don't see the parent class being on the build path if the inner class isn't. I would believe that somehow the support Fragment is being using by v13 instead of the regular Fragment and that the error isn't saying what the actual problem is, but that is why I posted :-). Thanks for trying to help!